# OpenLayers print preview

Tags: openlayers, printing

I'm trying to accomplish something similar to what you have in Google Earth, if you print the map.
You have an area, where you can see what you will get on the paper when you print, which have the right aspect ratio according to the DIN-Format.

[image]

I checked the OpenLayers example how to print from here https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html.

But you actually don't get what you see, depend on the DPI I choose I can see map sections beyond the viewport.

What should I keep in mind if I want to implement this feature?

Comment: The example fits the viewport into a paper size.  If your viewport aspect ratio is different you would need a custom paper size.

Comment: To fit the paper size into the viewport you would need to change `var scaling = Math.min(width / size[0], height / size[1]);` to use `Math.max`

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: If you change to fit the paper inside the viewport then you can have a postrender event to highlight the region which would be printed https://codesandbox.io/s/export-pdf-forked-m6iy8

Comment: @TomazicM the linked example has relevant code

Comment: Q/A on GIS SE site are not intended only to solve problem of particular user, but be helpful resource for anybody with similar questions/problems. That's the reason question has to be complete in itself and include all relevant code, since outside links tend to get lost in time and also that there is no need to visit other sites to get complete picture of what the problem/question is.

Comment: @Mike that is basically a complete solution, thanks. I thought, that I need to consider the preview bounds in the printing process.